# добавление функции в генератор

Tags: python

есть генератор простых чисел:

```
def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if not number % prime:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            yield number


for number in prime_numbers_generator(n=1000):
    print(number)
```

и есть функция, которая выдает числа палиндромы

```
def paliPrime(n):
    a = 0
    b = n
    a += 1
    for i in range(a, b):
        paliPrime = True
        if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
            if i > 2:
                for a in range(2, i):
                    if i % a == 0:
                        paliPrime = False
                        break
                if paliPrime:
                    print(i)

paliPrime(1000)
```

Подскажите, как можно сделать, чтобы она брала и проверяла простые числа из генератора, и если те являются палиндромами, то выводила их с пометкой true рядом, а если нет, то выводились простые числа без пометки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if not number % prime:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            yield number


def isPali(n):
    return True if str(n)[::-1] == str(n) else False


for number in prime_numbers_generator(n=1000):
   print(number, isPali(number), sep=' ')
```

Comment: Спасибо, неожиданно оказалось все проще чем я думал